# Traduction française de « commitment » (gestion de projet)

Tags: traduction, anglais

Dans le cadre de la traduction d'un document sur la gestion de projet, je peine sur « *commitment* ». *Engagement* (sens 2 de mon Robert) me paraît trop imprécis à cause des multiples sens du mot en français. *Pacte*, *contrat*, *obligation* sont dans le bon champ sémantique, mais peut-être un peu forts pour quelque chose qui n'est pas forcément aussi formalisé, et parfois relativement implicite.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Après avoir lu les différentes utilisations de *commitment* en anglais, il me semble qu'*engagement* soit la meilleure traduction dans ce contexte.

Si le verbe *engager* a effectivement plusieurs définitions en français, sa forme pronominale n'en a que trois et ne peuvent être confondues.

En ce sens, **s'engager** signifie se lier par une promesse. Ainsi, **si je m'engage à faire quelque chose pour toi, je te promets de le faire pour toi**. Quand on signe un contrat, on s'engage à respecter les termes de ce contrat.

Du coup, comme tu le dis, contrat et pacte sont des mots plus forts qu'engagement. Un pacte s'utilisera plus dans le cadre d'une convention entre pays, d'un traité. Un contrat aboutit généralement à la signature d'un document, comme par exemple un contrat de travail.

Dans un **contrat** ou un **pacte**, il y a engagement de deux ou plusieurs parties. Dans le mot **obligation**, il y a une notion de contrainte derrière, comme si on ne pouvait se libérer ou faire autrement. À mon sens, le mot engagement a un sens plus large que les deux premiers.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec la réponse. Mais mes bases de Droit m'obligent à rappeler cette précision: un contrat n'est pas forcément écrit, par contre il est forcément explicite.